# Physical Significance behind retracing light rays

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

My question is pretty basic. Suppose in plane mirrors, for example, when we draw reflected rays we produce them backwards . Moreover, we say that the point object is located at the intersection of the two rays. What is the physical significance behind this? Why is it that we observe the image here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eye can only process the light which enters it so the image formed on the retina is the same in both circumstances provided that object $O'$ is a lateral inversion of object $O$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The light rays which are reflected from a mirror, form an image on the retina of our eye, as they converge on the retina due to the presence of eye lens, which is convex in nature.

The retracing of light rays backwards while drawing ray diagrams simply tells us how the image will look as if we were seeing the image. The diverged rays are converged at a point behind the mirror by retracing,  which shows the position of the image behind the mirror, i.e. the distance of the image from the mirror that we understand or feel when we see the image. This is the physical significance.

Answer (score 0):

The image is formed by us by this technique because we basically know the nature of light i.e. it travels along the shortest path.

So, where we form the image by our method, we simply denote that if there had been a source of light(where the rays intersect after reflecting) then the light of the source would have travelled along this path.